# Probability that a sequence of 0,1 appears in another

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> What is the probability that a given sequence $s$ of length $k$ of zeros and ones appears at least once in randomly generated sequence $S$ of length of $n$ of zeros and ones where the probabilities of appearances of zeros and ones are equal in $S$?

Depending on $s$, the probability changes and this makes it hard. I have found the answer when $s$ is all ones.

Comment: As you point out, the probability varies by sequence.  What form of answer do you want?  Is this from a textbook?  Maybe [De Bruijn graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_graph) will be useful?

Comment: @BrianTung Can we solve this as a general problem independent of the string? This is not from a textbook

Comment: If the probability varies, then what kind of general solution are you hoping for?  Sure can't be a single value.  Tight lower and upper bounds?

Comment: @antkam  I even don't know the answer depends on what characteristics of $s$. It might be the number of zeros or even more. By the general answer I mean a formulation that works for all input $s$. For instance, if we realize it only depends on the number of zeros, then the general answer would be giving the answer based on the number of zeros.

Comment: Albert - then the answer is related to the De Brujin graphs that Brian was talking about.  I keep thinking I've seen this question answered here at MSE (at least for a specific $s$ like $HTHT$ or similar, but demonstrating the principle), but I can't find anything after a quick search...